# Failed AJAX called for association records in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index page where I display all messages for a user using a partial. Each message can have multiple comments. As of now the process is working but everytime a user add a comment it refreshes the entire page. I am trying to have an AJAX call for each refresh, but I get an error when modifying the Create method in the Comments.controller. Does anybody knows how I should write the response after the comment is saved please?
My Comment.controller:

```
def create
    @message = Message.find(params[:message_id])
    @comment = @message.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    CommentMailer.new_comment(@comment).deliver_now
    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        @comment = Message.find(params[:message_id]).update_columns(msg_responded_status: "1")
        @comment = Message.find(params[:message_id]).update_columns(msg_responded_time: Time.current) @message = Message.find(params[:message_id])
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

My `messages/show.html.erb` which is nested in `message/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= raw @message.description %>
<div id="comments"> <%= render @message.comments %>
</div>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<div id="comments_form"> <%= render 'comments/form' %>
</div>
```

`_form.html.erb` partial:

```
%= simple_form_for ([@message, @message.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.cktext_area :content, label: (t :Reply_to_message) , :input_html => {:rows => 15} %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-custom', label: (t :CreateComment), remote: true %>

<% end %>
```

I created a `comments/create.js.erb` with:

```
$("#comments").html("<%= j render partial: '@message.comments' %>");
```

Error code:

```
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("content", "message_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "<p>baam</p>\r\n"], ["message_id", 189], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2018-11-12 02:53:45.431470"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-12 02:53:45.431470"]]
   (1.7ms)  commit transaction
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 741ms (ActiveRecord: 11.6ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (CommentsController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []):
```

is `comment` the right folder for the create.js.erb? what action should I require after the comment is saved please?

Comment: Can you post the error you got ?

Comment: Show the code where you're making the AJAX call and also share the error you're getting.

Comment: Hey, just amended the initial post to include the error and the form.

Comment: you need to add `remote: true` in your form tag instead of `submit button tag`...